# pg_trgm in Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

pg_trgm is supported according to [Amazon's docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport), but my search scope is no longer working after a switch from Heroku's postgres to Amazon.

```
  pg_search_scope :trigram_search, :against => [:first_name, :last_name], :using => {:trigram => {:threshold => 0.5}}
```

Now I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function similarity(text, unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...is' || ' ''')), 0)) AS rank FROM "people" WHERE ((similarity...
>                                                                ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Do I need to do something extra to enable the trigram extension?

Comment: Can you DROP and re-CREATE tablefunc many developers has faced this issue of pg_trgm not working and recreating worked for them.

Comment: Depending on how you migrated from Heroku to RDS, there could be a chance that the extensions (like `pg_trgm`) that you had loaded in your original DB weren't loaded in the new one. Can you log into your new production DB and check with `\dx` that those extensions are there?